# Angular Jasmine Test HTML Injection Fails

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, jasmine, jhipster

I am unable to inject my HTML template into my Jasmine test. How do I resolve this error?

> Error: This test module uses the component FooDetailComponent which is using a "templateUrl" or "styleUrls", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test.

My test clearly calls `compileComponents()`, and also sets the `templateUrl`, so I'm unclear on how to proceed.

### `foo-detail.component.ts` Definition:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    templateUrl: './foo-detail.component.html'
})
export class FooDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy { ... }
```

### foo-detail.component.spec.ts:

```
describe('Component Tests', () => {

    describe('Foo Management Detail Component', () => {
        let comp: FooDetailComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooDetailComponent>;
        let service: FooService;

        beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [FooDetailComponent],
                providers: [
                    MockBackend,
                    BaseRequestOptions,
                    {
                        provide: Router,
                        useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy("navigate"); }
                    },
                    FooService
                ]
            }).overrideComponent(FooDetailComponent, {
                set: {
                      // This line, when uncommmented, allows the test to run, but 
                      //  doesn't recognize a template:
                    // template: ''
                      // This line, when uncommented, induces the error:
                    templateUrl : '../../../../../../main/webapp/app/entities/foo/foo-detail.component.html',
                    styleUrls: ['../../../../../../main/webapp/app/entities/foo/foo-create.scss']
                }
            }).compileComponents();
        }));

        beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooDetailComponent);
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;
            service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(FooService);
        });


        describe('OnInit', () => {
            it('Should call load all on init', () => {
            // GIVEN
            spyOn(service, 'find');
            // WHEN
            comp.ngOnInit();
            // THEN
            service.find("testidentifier");
            expect(service.find).toHaveBeenCalledWith("testidentifier");
            });
        });
    });

});
```

### Full Stack Trace

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load %3Cdiv%20id=%22%7B%7Bid%7D%7D <entire htmlenoded template>
resolvePromise@spec/entry.ts:110657:78
resolvePromise@spec/entry.ts:110627:31
spec/entry.ts:110704:31
invokeTask@spec/entry.ts:110310:36
onInvokeTask@spec/entry.ts:109806:49
invokeTask@spec/entry.ts:110309:48
runTask@spec/entry.ts:110077:57
drainMicroTaskQueue@spec/entry.ts:110470:42
run@spec/entry.ts:133028:29
spec/entry.ts:133041:31
flush@spec/entry.ts:59106:11
Error: This test module uses the component FooCreateComponent which is using a "templateUrl" or "styleUrls", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test. in spec/entry.ts (line 10169)
_initIfNeeded@spec/entry.ts:10169:91
createComponent@spec/entry.ts:10247:31
createComponent@spec/entry.ts:10076:48
spec/entry.ts:85022:56
invoke@spec/entry.ts:110277:31
onInvoke@spec/entry.ts:109782:45
invoke@spec/entry.ts:110276:40
run@spec/entry.ts:110027:49
spec/entry.ts:109481:37
spec/entry.ts:9456:34
spec/entry.ts:9503:33
invoke@spec/entry.ts:110277:31
onInvoke@spec/entry.ts:109020:45
onInvoke@spec/entry.ts:109779:47
invoke@spec/entry.ts:110276:40
run@spec/entry.ts:110027:49
spec/entry.ts:9498:32
onHandleError@spec/entry.ts:109030:31
onHandleError@spec/entry.ts:109787:52
handleError@spec/entry.ts:110281:50
runGuarded@spec/entry.ts:110043:55
_loop_1@spec/entry.ts:110539:57
microtaskDrainDone@spec/entry.ts:110548:24
drainMicroTaskQueue@spec/entry.ts:110478:36
run@spec/entry.ts:133028:29
spec/entry.ts:133041:31
flush@spec/entry.ts:59106:11
Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for create()
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>) in /myHomeDir/portal-frontend/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js (line 2067)
spec/entry.ts:85032:22
invoke@spec/entry.ts:110277:31
onInvoke@spec/entry.ts:109782:45
invoke@spec/entry.ts:110276:40
run@spec/entry.ts:110027:49
spec/entry.ts:109481:37
spec/entry.ts:9456:34
spec/entry.ts:9503:33
invoke@spec/entry.ts:110277:31
onInvoke@spec/entry.ts:109020:45
onInvoke@spec/entry.ts:109779:47
invoke@spec/entry.ts:110276:40
run@spec/entry.ts:110027:49
spec/entry.ts:9498:32
onHandleError@spec/entry.ts:109030:31
onHandleError@spec/entry.ts:109787:52
handleError@spec/entry.ts:110281:50
runGuarded@spec/entry.ts:110043:55
_loop_1@spec/entry.ts:110539:57
microtaskDrainDone@spec/entry.ts:110548:24
drainMicroTaskQueue@spec/entry.ts:110478:36
run@spec/entry.ts:133028:29
spec/entry.ts:133041:31
flush@spec/entry.ts:59106:11
```

### Stack:

- Angular 2.4.4
- Typescript 2.1.5
- Jasmine-core 2.5.2
- Node: ">=7.5.0"
- JHipster 4.5.2

Comment: Would be better if you could provide a plunker for this.

Comment: JHipster supports only LTS version of Node, have you tried running on node 6.x?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou if this has anything to do with JHipster, it would provide proof that server + client scaffolding tools are a bad idea. Why are you using an old version of TypeScript? JJ Zabkar, Also, have you verified that the path exists relative to the test file?

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes, the relative path exists. Double-checked it even after my IDE auto-populated it.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou this test is representative of a JHipster-generated test, but our non-JHipster tests still suffer the same fate: unable to consume a `templateUrl `.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe you need to call `compileComponents` from `beforeEach` because you are using a highly stateful and error prone testing setup. Consider reading [Eric Elliot's thoughts on this subject for further insight](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/why-i-use-tape-instead-of-mocha-so-should-you-6aa105d8eaf4). Also, why do you have multiple `beforeEach` blocks in a single test (one of which is using a suspicious looking `async(....)` helper)?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sorry, not following: my test calls `compileComponents()` already.  Am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: Not sure, I cannot grock that much stateful test configuration, ~40 lines of configuration for a simple test, mutable variables everywhere, a function named `async` used inside of a `beforeEach` block, spies and mocks, the whole thing is crap. Most frameworks have  awkward test configurations but Angular 2/4's takes the cake for disgusting and unmaintainable.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I agree; the generated code is a bit crufty. I've hopefully removed some of the crufty bits to try to expose the key parts a bit more; thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it thanks to @DBosley and @AluanHaddad.  Here's what I did:

1. Refactor my code to use the `then` pattern as suggested by @DBosley.
2. Re-enable `templateUrl` within `overrideComponent`.
3. Update my `karma.conf.js` per [this modification found on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5662#issuecomment-249783974), which yields much more descriptive stack traces:

   ```
   Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
   'jhi-alert-error' is not a known element:
       1. If 'jhi-alert-error' is an Angular component, then verify that it is 
         part of this module.
       2. If 'jhi-alert-error' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA"
         to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. 
       ("</div>
           <hr>
           [ERROR ->]<jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>
           <dl class="row">
           </dl>
       "): FooComponent@4:4
       Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("

           <button type="button"
                   [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { ..."
               "): FooComponent
   ```
4. Fix the missing *N* dependencies by adding mocks in the `providers` section of my `TestBed.configureTestingModule`:

   ```
   (first time)
   Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for JhiAlertErrorComponent!
   (Nth time)
   Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for BarService!
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think you're doing unnecessary work. If I'm reading your test config correctly, you're declaring the component you want to test but then you are overriding it with its own template and stylesheet.

This [link](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/testing/components/overriding.html) has a good example explaining why you would want to override the template or styles. If you're using `.overrideComponent` and you're just setting the styles and template to the files it's already set to use in it's `@Component` decorator, the whole call to `.overrideComponent` is unnecessary.

To address the problem with the fixture complaining your component isn't compiled, I see you're missing a `.then()` call after `.compileComponents()`

Based on that documentation, I think you might want something like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [FooDetailComponent],
        providers: [
            MockBackend,
            BaseRequestOptions,
            {
                provide: Router,
                useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy("navigate"); }
            },
            FooService
        ]
    }).compileComponents().then(()=>{
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooDetailComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(FooService);
    });
}));
```

If you do actually need the overrides, just copy/paste the contents of the above `.then()` call and remove your second `beforeEach()` as it will be unnecessary.

Comment: @Dhraz thanks for the suggestion and example code. I tried your code, but I still get the `Failed to load %3Cdiv` (my html template) error. I'm not sure how to identify what it is about my HTML template that is problematic, or if that's even the issue.

Comment: I've never encountered that error before. I'd need to see your template (or a simplified one that has the same problem) to see if there's a problem in there. I've wrapped 15-20 components with testbed setups nearly identical to this and have never experienced issues like you're having.

Comment: Update! It looks like the target email template has some other (un-injected) custom directives, but I'm not sure of the proper way to inject or mock them.

Comment: @JJZabkar I use this to mock components I don't want to run in my unit tests: https://medium.com/@cnunciato/a-simple-mock-component-for-angular-2-d79bd58a7b31